# Fastest way to match column from one file to another

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files which both have over a million lines and I want to print out the match from the first column of file 1 with the second of file 2.

file_1

```
SNP_A-2131660   1   0.0021
SNP_A-1967418   2   0.0005
SNP_A-1969580   2   0.0011
SNP_A-4263484   1   0.0024
SNP_A-1978185   0   0.0014
SNP_A-4264431   0   0.0038
SNP_A-1980898   2   0.0050
SNP_A-1983139   0   0.0011
```

file_2

```
"AFFX-SNP_10000979" "rs4147951"
"AFFX-SNP_10009702" "rs2022235"
"SNP_A-2131660" "rs6425720"
"AFFX-SNP_10021569" "rs12997193"
"AFFX-SNP_10026879" "rs9933410"
"AFFX-SNP_10029725" "rs7142489"
"AFFX-SNP_10034687" "rs1350088"
```

matches.txt

```
"SNP_A-2131660" "rs6425720"
```

Right now I am doing, but it is so slow. Is there a faster way?

```
awk '{print $1}' file_1 | while read -r a; do grep -H $a file_2; done >> matches.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following awk.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} {val=$1;gsub(/\"/,"",val)} (val in a)' file_1 file_2
```

If you want to redirect above command's output into a output file you could do > output.txt(or whatever you like the name for output file) at the end of the command too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, and setting field separator `FS='"'` after reading first file,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}$2 in a' file1 FS='"' file2

# OR

awk -v q='"' 'FNR==NR{a[q $1 q];next}$1 in a' file1 file2
```

It will be faster among all solution posted till now, as we are not sorting file, replacing double quotes and joining them

Test Results :

```
$ cat f1
SNP_A-2131660   1   0.0021
SNP_A-1967418   2   0.0005
SNP_A-1969580   2   0.0011
SNP_A-4263484   1   0.0024
SNP_A-1978185   0   0.0014
SNP_A-4264431   0   0.0038
SNP_A-1980898   2   0.0050
SNP_A-1983139   0   0.0011

$ cat f2
"AFFX-SNP_10000979" "rs4147951"
"AFFX-SNP_10009702" "rs2022235"
"SNP_A-2131660" "rs6425720"
"AFFX-SNP_10021569" "rs12997193"
"AFFX-SNP_10026879" "rs9933410"
"AFFX-SNP_10029725" "rs7142489"
"AFFX-SNP_10034687" "rs1350088"

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}$2 in a' f1 FS='"' f2
"SNP_A-2131660" "rs6425720"

# OR
$ awk -v q='"' 'FNR==NR{a[q $1 q];next}$1 in a' f1 f2
"SNP_A-2131660" "rs6425720"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible tool is join, but you need some preprocessing and some post-processing:

```
sort < file1 > file1_sorted
sort < file2 | sed 's/^"\([^"]*\)"/\1/' > file2_sorted
join file1_sorted file2_sorted -1 1 -2 1
```

Gives:

```
SNP_A-2131660 1 0.0021 "rs6425720"
```